# How many continuities are there in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

The new movie is going to retcon the old Broly movies. This made me think how many continuities do we have in Dragon Ball.

- The old anime series and/or manga were one (or two?)
- The old movies
- Dragon Ball GT
- Dragon Ball Heroes. How many continuities do we have in this set? There are 2 mangas written by different persons and one anime. is it 1,2 or 3?
- Battle of Gods and Resurrection of F. They are different than the anime and manga versions.
- Dragon Ball Super anime is different than the Dragon Ball Super manga. Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken, Super Saiyan Rage, Ultra Instinct Omen and Super Saiyan Blue Evolution exists in the anime but not in the manga.
- And what about the new movie? Does it fit with the anime continuity, with the manga continuity or it's a new continuity?
- What about the spinoffs? (Jaco, Yamcha manga, etc.) What about the Tv specials?

To know which stories are independent of the others is important to understand any Dragon Ball story.

Therefore my question is, How many continuities are there in Dragon Ball?